# Как оценить первый ход?

Tags: алгоритм, разработка-игр

Довольно известная игра. В данном случае убираются блоки одного цвета, состоящие из 3 и более элементов, при клике на них. Все вышестоящие элементы падают вниз. Если при этом возникают пустые ряды между фигурами, они сдвигаются влево. Цель: убрать с поля все элементы.

[image: Игровая ситуация]

Полным перебором всех комбинаций было определено, что при первом ходе: 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 или 7 мы в 100% проигрыше. Как это алгоритмически описать без перебора? У меня пока получился только алгоритм с "весовой" оценкой каждого возможного начала, что совсем не даёт 100%. Могу смоделировать дгугие ситуации при необходимости.

Comment: Сходу кажется, что данная задача неразрешима без полного беребора (возможно, получится сделать какие-то отсечения, но опять же, это будет перебор и NP-полная задача). С другой стороны, Вы можете попробовать применить здесь Динамическое программирование по изломоному профилю. Но я совсем не уверен, что получится что-то изобрести. http://informatics.mccme.ru/mod/book/view.php?id=290&chapterid=78

Comment: Что касается глобального оптимума, то у меня возникают некоторые сомнения: зачем оно Вам? Как правило, в таких играх интересует локальный экстремум, близкий к глобальному. В связи с этим можно предложить эвристику (как Вы и сделали) и получить неплохое приближение точного ответа.

Comment: @hedgehogues, проблема в том, что когда эвристика спотыкается, начинается по сути полный перебор, т.к. это приближение и даже ход с самой худшей оценкой мы не можем отсечь на 100%... а при (грубо 2^n) это больно. В данном примере у нас 10 возможных начал при чём каждый ход не гарантирует их уменьшения, они могут несколько ходов оставаться 10, а могут и прибавиться. А если их 20? Получается если эвристика спотыкается в начале (нет правил без исключений), то мы зависли на долго.

Comment: @hedgehogues, по сути да. Это попытка улучшить эвристику, лучше тут врядли что-то придумаешь. С какой бы вы подошли стороны при её создании? Может я что-то не увидел, а каждая мелочь может сильно улучшить результат.

Comment: если есть возможность осуществлять перебор, то можно решить оптимизационную задачу. Т.е. построить модель (например, нейросеть, т.е. регрессию) (f(состояние) - точное решение)^2 -> min. Другим вариантом является оценка качества шага. Например, очевидно, что коль скоро некоторое скопление квадратиков, которое можно единовременно убрать, окружают преимущественно квадраты одинакового цвета убирать практически всегда выгодно.